# Variable Frame-rate Animation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time, plot

In matlab if I have a array, namely a matrix whose first column is time and other two are coordinates, and if I plot it:

```
ti=myarray(:,1);
xi=myarray(:,2);
yi=myarray(:,3);

for i=1:length(ti)
   plot(xi(i),yi(i));hold on;
   Mov(i)=getframe;
end
```

This records my movie uniformly. When I play

```
movie(Mov,1,20)
```

It assumes frames are equi-chronologically distributed.

Can I make a plot so that movie plays at time specified by it?

Note that `pause` if possible, might not be an option for me. System time is slow(`10ms` precision). And combining slow processing of matlab and low precision of system time will give undesirable results. Also note that my `fps` can go higher than `100`. But if this can be implemented, I welcome it.

Comment: Once I wanted to do so (write such movie into a file), but I don't think there's a movie format for *variable frame-rate* movie. If it's just for presenting a result to human eye, you can find the approximate minimum time-step and multiply the frames with longer show time accordingly. This will result in a movie with larger size since you are increasing the number of frames.     Happy to hear a real solution!

Comment: @pm89: not so sure about that: looking at [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_frame_rate) and then the list of containers that support it found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats), it should be possible to do this, at least in theory. Not a clue how to do it in MATLAB though :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Thanks for good news! But unfortunately `AVI` is among the few which does not actually support it; in your [list of containers link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) about `AVI` it says: "Although AVI is not designed for variable framerates, it is possible to use them without creating a non-standard file by using 0-byte chunks for skipped frames. However it requires framerate to be set to Least common multiple of all framerates used, and produces slight overhead compared to true VFR."

Comment: @pm89: well, I suppose that's one way to work around it in MATLAB...I dunno, I would just write a set of frames (individual JPEGs) to disk, accompanied by a text file mapping each frame to a specific time. Then use an external video conversion tool to make the VFR video file; MATLAB simply does not seem the right tool for this job :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create variable framerate movies you can use my [QTWriter](http://horchler.github.io/QTWriter/) class. It's a single easy-to-use class file inspired by Matlab's [VideoWriter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html) class that allows native export of QuickTime encoded movies in several formats suitable for Matlab-style graphics. Nothing else is needed, not even QuickTime (unless you want to playback the output files). Notably, It supports Quicktime's ability to continuously vary the frame rate.

Here's some example code that produces a movie similar to [this QuickTime movie](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter/raw/master/peaks.mov):

```
% Prepare new movie file using the default PNG compression
movObj = QTWriter('peaks.mov');

% Create an animation
hf = figure; Z = peaks; surfc(Z); frames = 100;
axis tight; set(gca,'nextplot','replacechildren');

% Animate plot and write movie
for k = 0:frames
    surfc(sin(2*pi*k/frames)*Z,Z);

    % Vary the frame-rate
    movObj.FrameRate = k;

    % Write each frame to the file
    writeMovie(movObj,getframe(hf));
end

% Finish writing movie and close file
close(movObj);
```

Within Matlab, variable framerate QuickTime movies can be played back with Matlab's [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) class (I'm not sure about this on Windows/Linux) by passing `readerobj.FrameRate` to the [`movie`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movie.html) function. If you convert the output movies to another container format (e.g., AVI) or codec that doesn't support variable framerates (or if your conversion software doesn't) then you'll need to set the framerate of the converted movie to the highest framerate in the QuickTime file. This may well result in larger files - one can think or variable framerate movies as temporally-compressed (a bit like is done with inter-frame compression).

The framerate parameter does not have have infinite resolution and range so one may need to adjust the `'TimeScale'` parameter as well. Any movie may have difficulty playing back at high framerates depending on the users hardware, computational cost of decoding, and the data rate. Normally, players just drop frames. `QTWriter` also has a `'PlayAllFrames'` option that forces QuickTime Player to render every frame -this may result in non-realtime playback however. Alternatively, one can choose the 'Photo TIFF' compression type which decodes faster at the cost of slightly larger file sizes.

The code is open source (BSD), hosted on [Github](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter), and I welcome contributors. There is still much room for optimization and improvement. You can see another example and resultant movie on the [project webpage](http://horchler.github.io/QTWriter/).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for developing and sharing!